# BabylonJS Drawing a Line

Tags: javascript, webgl, babylonjs

I am currently attempting to trace the path of an object in BabylonJS.

To do this I would like to draw a line between the existing location and the previous location.

The closest I've been able to come is a cube.

```
var plane = BABYLON.Mesh.CreatePlane("Plane", 50, scene);
```

Here is a link to [one of the tutorials](https://github.com/BabylonJS/Babylon.js/wiki/02-Basic-elements), but none of them talk about lines.

Does anyone know how to draw a line using BabylonJS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lines aren't currently implemented in Babylonjs. The author suggests creating a triangle where you want the line. More here...
http://www.html5gamedevs.com/topic/2235-draw-a-line/#entry15013

Comment: This is funny. I was just about to answer this question. That thread is actually mine. Take a look at the screen names.

Answer (score 2):

BabylonJS can do lines now... and much, much more!

http://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/how_to_use_curve3

https://doc.babylonjs.com/babylon101/parametric_shapes

http://doc.babylonjs.com/how_to/how_to_use_path3d

:)